# Can i make a custom tf.estimator without using feature columns?

Tags: tensorflow

i.e. can i directly feed tensors with numerical data into the model_fn of a custom estimator?

Creating a numerical column and do a mapping from keys to values seems to be an overkill for me, who only works on image data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The `features` argument to your `model_fn` can simply be a tensor, or a dict mapping strings to tensors in the case of multiple inputs. This also means that your `input_fn` can simply return such objects.